# How were Hiro's time halting scenes filmed?

Tags: effects, heroes

In **many** scenes in Heroes, we witness Hiro Nakamura display his ability to stop time:

[image]

However, also in these scenes, we witness him interact with the scene, whether it be interacting with stopped objects or just to move around.

My question is **how was this accomplished?**  Is it a simple CGI trick or a combination of that with actors/extras having to remain **REALLY** still?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One of the DVDs from the series has an excellent special feature showing the process used. It was often a combination of Green Screen/CGI and staged actors and props. So to answer the question it is a fusion of both.

The example shown on the DVD is a scene in the street where he's moving through a crowded shopping district and rescuing a child from an accident.

Note: No CGI trick is "Simple" ;)

[image]

Comment: Ah! Green stands to prop the actors. Clever.

Answer (score 7):

From [fxguide.com](http://www.fxguide.com/featured/heroic_vfx_stargate_digital_and_nbcs_heroes):

> [image: To achieve the effect of frozen time special rigs were used]
>   [image: To achieve this effect the crew had to make sure even the wind was not blowing the tree leaves]
>
> In “[bullet time](http://youtu.be/_KtghA0rkDY)” or the classic multiple camera shoot, all action is
>   frozen and the path of the cameras cannot be very complex. Without
>   either the shooting time nor the resources for a computerized camera
>   rig, the team needed to be inventive. The solution was to produce
>   special frozen mounts and rigs to allow for actors to just act still
>   and frozen while filmed by a normal camera.
>
> To make the effect work there is also filmed a semi clean plate. While
>   this plate is not motion control, it provides enough textures for the
>   team to project onto dummy geometry and make a convincing final shot.
>   The finishing touches are added by having some CG objects seamingly
>   suspended in the air. This approach allowed the character Hiro to
>   actually interact with the set and ‘walk’ the visual effect in the
>   same pass as the main plate photography solving both eyelines and
>   removing the need for any motion control.

---

- The company that worked on it uploaded a [video](http://youtu.be/Xmo8m2_Ut78) to their YouTube channel about the visual effects of the 3rd season. The making of the effect is discussed at around 2:03.
- It's not Heroes, but [here](http://youtu.be/1REyjUmf_DI) is a quite detailed video about the same effect achieved with the help of motion control.